# I can't specify why the output is not right?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I wanted a program to calculate the first natural number that gives a positive value from the following math. function. f(x) = 0.001 - (1/x)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


long double abso (long double x)
{
    return (x > 0 ? x : -x);
};

int main()
{
    long double y=0,x=0;

    for (register long double n=0; y<=0 ;)
    {
        n++;
        y = 0.001 - (1/x);
        x=n;
    };
    cout<< "The number is "<< x <<'\n';
    system ("pause");
}
```

It's supposed to give 1001, but it gave me 1002.

Can anyone refer me to the error in the code?

Comment: That's not surprising. The `x` used in `1/x` is from last iteration.

Comment: I get `1001`. It must be caused by floating point precision issues.

Comment: [I got 1001](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=0f024e7427b2c8fa)

Comment: Why do you post a function that is not used in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop `for (register long double n=0; y<=0 ;)` will break once `y > 0`.

At the point the last assignments were:

```
   n++;
   y = 0.001 - (1/x);
   x=n;
```

So the `x` that verified your equation is equal `n-1`, not n, hence the incorrect output.

You can write thing much simply with a `while` loop and without an additional `n` which is useless here (except for the `register` modifier, but if you really need it _ I doubt it _ put it on x) :

```
while ( y<=0 )
{
    y = 0.001 - (1/++x);
}
cout<< "The number is "<< x <<'\n';
```

Comment: "The loop for (register long double n=0; y<=0 ;) will break once y <= 0" Don't you mean "once y > 0"?

Comment: I took 0 as positive (but you're right that in Algebra , 0 is not positive. I edit.

Answer (score 0):

Assign x first before dividing it with one. You can't divide 1 by 0. 1 divided by 0 is actually an error.

```
for (register long double n=0; y<=0 ;)
    {
        n++;

        x=n;
        y = 0.001 - (1/x);
    };
```

I hope it will help